# python while loop printing each line

Tags: python, while-loop

```
user_input = input("Please enter a number: ") user_input = 
int(user_input) total = 0
i = 1
while i<=user_input:
    total += i
    i += 1
    print(total)
```

Output is:

```
Please enter a number: 5
1
3
6
10
15
```

But I want it to print only the last value. Kindly help out.

Comment: Move the print out of the loop and after it.

Comment: The current total will be printed each time `print(total)` is executed. If you don't want this statement to execute during each loop iteration, don't put it in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to call the print function from outside the loop and by that you will get one print

```
user_input = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
total = 0
i = 1
while i<=user_input:
    total += i
    i += 1
print(total)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was calling print function within loop

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print only the last value, you need to get the print function out of the loop

```
i = 1
total = 0

while i<=user_input:
   total += i
   i += 1
   
print(total)
```